# Сортировка данных в бинарных файлах

Tags: c, сортировка, binary-file

Есть такая задачка:

Данные о треугольниках хранятся в бинарных файлах. Необходимо скопировать их в файлрезультат, упорядочивая по возрастанию/убыванию (в ОП все данные не загружать):

- информация о треугольниках хранится в виде трех целых чисел (длины сторон треугольника). Считаем, что каждая тройка чисел образует треугольник;
- сортировку осуществляем по площадям треугольников. В исходных файлах данные о треугольниках упорядочены по возрастанию/убыванию площадей;
- количество исходных файлов заранее неизвестно – функции с переменным количеством параметров;
- сортировка по возрастанию/убыванию – указатели на функции

В одном файле может храниться как один, так и несколько треугольников. Для их хранения используется массив структур, для определения его размера в конец записывается -1 для всех членов структуры. Структура выглядит следующим образом:

```
struct Triangle // структура для хранения длин сторон треугольника
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Подскажите, как можно отсортировать данные в бинарных файлах, не загружая все данные в ОП. Используется язык C.

Comment: Возможно, тут подойдёт сортировка слиянием https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC

Comment: @CrazyElf, а как можно посимвольно считать массив из файла и так же посимвольно записать массив в файл, чтобы полностью его не выгружать в ОП?

Comment: Ну не посимвольно, а поэлементно. Считывать в объёме одной структуры, например, за раз. Ну это ж не готовый рецепт, а чтобы подумать над вариантами.

Comment: В DOS когда-то большие файлы сортировали merge sort с использованием временных файлов. Это один вариант. Второй вариант - если вы работаете в Windows - использоватьб отображение файла в оперативную память (наверняка в Linux'ах есть аналогичная функциональность).

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, речь всё-таки идёт о написании программы, а не об использовании существующих команд сортировки.

В условии задачи сказано, что исходные файлы уже отсортированы. Значит, необходимо выполнить не сортировку, а только лишь слияние, что гораздо проще.

Напишите функцию слияния с такой сигнатурой:

```
int merge(int left, int right, int out) 
    // left - файловый дескриптор левого входного файла
    // right - файловый дескриптор правого входного файла
    // out - файловый дескриптор выходного файла
```

Эта функция сливает два входных файла в один выходной. Алгоритм её работы абсолютно тривиальный - считываем по записи из каждого файла. Та запись, которая "больше" идёт в выходной. В том входном, из которого записали в выходной, считываем следующую. Если записи кончились в одном из входных - тупо копируем оставшиеся записи из другого файла.

Имея такую функцию легко пишем функцию *main()* - он представляет собой цикл перебора всех входных файлов. На первом шаге берём два первых входных и сливаем их в первый рабочий.

На втором и последующем шагах берём очередной входной и предшествующий рабочий и сливаем их в новый рабочий.

Процесс повторяется до тех пор, пока не слили последний входной с предпоследним рабочим. Результат этого слияния и будет результатом работы всей программы.

Читать файлы надо не по байтам или строкам, а по записям. Соответственно, открывать файлы нужно в двоичном режиме:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int left, right, out;
struct Triangle a;
size_t len;

left = open("Первый_файл", O_RDONLY);
right = open("Второй_файл", O_RDONLY);
out = open("wrk",  O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);

len = read(left, &a, sizeof(a));

len = write(out, a,  sizeof(a));
```